# a-node.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined

Tags: aframe

When I load my aframe project, I get this error, don't know how to trace that to whatever problem it indicates in my own code. Using https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js

Here's the whole trace:

```
core:a-node:error Failure loading node:   TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
    at extendProperties (component.js:734)
    at i.callUpdateHandler (component.js:414)
    at i.updateProperties (component.js:298)
    at HTMLElement.updateComponent (a-entity.js:490)
    at HTMLElement.updateComponents (a-entity.js:456)
    at a-entity.js:249
    at a-node.js:127
```

How do I tell what node is the problem here? Any suggestions for tracing the problem are welcome.

FWIW, this is pretty much the identical stack trace of the problem reported for v0.8.2 over here https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3920 . That was reported fixed, and I have no idea if it is significant, but maybe it will help suggest what's the matter to someone?  Since that bug appears to have had something to do with a camera, let me show my camera entity:

```
      <a-entity id="mainCameraRig">
        <a-entity camera
                  id="mainCamera"
                  wasd-controls
                  look-controls>
        </a-entity>
      </a-entity>
```

Maybe something is wrong with that?

Thanks.

Comment: You’re in old A-Frame version. Use 1.0.3. Also provide browser used and link to example to reproduce

Comment: This appeared to be a timeout issue and went away with adding a large timeout value to the <a-assets> declaration.

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem in the latest version of AFrame (1.4.2) and webpack (5.83.1). I can confirm that adding a camera entity or component causes the above error. It doesn't seem to be an issue if you are importing AFrame via a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to elaborate on user3247073's answer.

Adding a timeout value seemed to have worked.

I am not sure of what stack you are using, but practically, this is how I solved my problem. I am using Angular, and Aframe v.1.3.0

component.html

```
<a-scene *ngIf="aSceneLoaded">
    <a-box></a-box>
    <a-camera></a-camera>
  </a-scene>
```

compontent.ts
...

```
aSceneLoaded = false; 

ngOnInit() {
   this.loadAScene();
}    
       
 loadAScene() {
   setTimeout(() => {
       this.aSceneLoaded = true;
   }, 1000);
 }
```

In other words, when the Angular component initializes (after its constructor is initialized), we call the function loadAScene, that starts the timeout.